# sharp edged to rounded borders using css?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a div element with a rounded border. I am aware of the use of the `border-radius`, but I noticed that using this property will curve the corners only, like the top-right, top-left etc. so i was wondering if there is some property to curve the side of a div element, something like `border-radius` for top, down, left and right.

For example, a div with a straight top, bottom and left but a rounded right side. i would like to create the right side so that it is more rounded at the top than the bottom.

My aim is to create a div element with rounded right side which will not affect the top and bottom sides. i mean the curve in the right side should stop as soon as it reached the top or bottom side. (so that the top and bottom remains straight rather than slightly curved).

Is there a way to get this effect using css?

Comment: tryout some CSS and then post the specific problem here.

Comment: You can specify the radius for each corner individually: `border-radius: 5px 10px 20px 50px` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius

Comment: Its also worth pointing out that you should also use -moz-border-radius: -webkit-border-radius: for better browser support

Comment: Hmmm, yes, you probably should, but in truth with the rapid release cycles and auto-upgrades, there's very few people still using browsers that require either of them - especially `-moz-`. (`-webkit-` might have a few very old macs and mobile devices that haven't been upgraded, but pretty much everyone on Firefox has upgraded past v3.6 by now)

Comment: NO you shouldn't! http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius Dropping prefixes encourages the browservendors to continue this standardization and users to upgrade to an up-to-date browser. Also it decreases filesize and increases maintainability drasticly. This is a comment, and not an answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can specify [horizontal and vertical border-radii](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius) via the slash notation to achieve such an effect...

```css
div{
    width:100px;height:100px;
    border:3px solid #bada55;
    border-radius:10px/50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This would set a vertical border-radius of 50% and a horizontal border-radius of 10px for all sides. You can define this for each corner individually (So you have up to eight values).

Comment: Didn't knew this `10px/50%` +1

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `border-radius` for this. You just have to be a bit more creative with the parameters you give it.

`border-radius` allows you to specify both a horizontal radius and a vertical radius for each corner. Using these gives you the flexibility to stretch a curve effect across the whole of one side your element if you wish.

An random example that makes an odd shaped box:

```
.myElement { border-radius: 24% 41% 31% 9%/44% 6% 32% 40%; }
```

And [here it is on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReuEz/).

Rather than give you loads of detailed examples, I'll link you to this site, which demonstrates the flexibility of `border-radius`, and allows you to design the shape you want: http://www.webtutorialplus.com/border-radius.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, thanks for the border-radius generator, but still the curve mostly takes place in the corners, is there a way to curve the side borders?

Comment: no, not really. if you want more than that, you're talking about free-form shapes rather than boxes. At that point, you want to switch to SVG rather than HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/` effect which defines the horizontal and vertical radii. 10px is horizontal, 100px is vertical

```
div
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px/100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

With the border radius set to `10px/100px` this makes the sides slightly curved. Set the left corners to 0 and you have only one side that is curved :)

http://jsfiddle.net/UWbKf/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
        td
        {
            padding: 0px 0px;
        }
        form
        {
            border: 2px solid #000000;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 400px;
            color:black;
            background-color: white;
        }
        body{
            background-color:grey;
            
        }
        
    </style>
    <style>
        body,html
        {
            height:100%;
            margin:0;
            display:flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items:center;
            background-color:grey;
            
        }
        div
        {
            width:350%;
            height:350%;
            background-color:#f0f0f0;
            border-radius:15px;
            display:flex;
            align-items:center;
            background-color:grey;
            .content{
               text-align: center;   
            }
            
        }
    </style>
```

now call  tag whwerever you want square with rounded edges

Comment: you have call the div tag